Is there any way to prevent USB file deletion?
I have some files that I want to make sure I don't delete. I was wondering if I could create a folder on a USB Drive, then password protect it?

https://superuser.com/questions/818314/make-some-content-on-usb-drive-read-only

Some USB drives have a "write protect" feature - I have seen both physical switches and software options.
Obviously the physical switch is good for accidental deletion protection where as the software option is designed for USB sticks you are sharing (for example a classroom environment).
I am not aware of a device that offers separation - i.e. provides both a read-only and read-write partition on the same device (its possible someone makes one), however you could simulate that by using two USB sticks and just plugging both in at once.

Adding to @Jamesfo:
This tool makes the process of write-protecting and un-protecting an NTFS-formatted USB-Stick quite easy:
https://www.sordum.org/8117/ntfs-drive-protection-v1-5/


You don't specify your OS. If you are on Windows, you can simply format the drive as NTFS, copy over your files, then remove all permissions except for "Read & execute"
Find the setting by right-clicking the folder in Explorer > Properties > Security > Advanced. I strongly advise you to read up on NTFS permissions before modifying anything. After doing so, you may also consider changing the folder's owner.
Another potential option on Windows is to enable the Recycle Bin on your USB drives. This is available through editing the registry. Set the key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\RecycleBinDrives to ffffffff (DWORD). You are strongly advised to back up your registry before making any changes.
